# When using Retrofit2 POST it's just doesn't work

Tags: php, android, retrofit, retrofit2

```
Retrofit rt;
rt=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2/").addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();


Foo foo=rt.create(Foo.class);

//Map<String,String> mapp=new HashMap<>();
//mapp.put("author","author");
Call<String> msg=foo.postJson("msg");

msg.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

        Log.v("STERLITAMAK", response.body().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.v("STERLITAMAK", t.toString());

    }
});
```

Interface code

```
public interface Foo {

@GET("Singleton")
Call<String> getJson(@Query("weneed") String author);

@POST("Singleton")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<String> postJson(@Field("weneed") String author);

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("Singleton")
Call<String> postJson1(@FieldMap Map<String,String> data);
}
```

PHP code on server

```
echo $_POST['weneed'];
```

The thing is, when i run the code, server just can't see POST request. But answer is correct. If i use getJson method of the interface, it will work. So problem probably not on the server.

Comment: Add t.prientstacktrace() on onFailure Method then show logcat error

Comment: @RajeshRajendiran Seems like i don't have errors. I wrote this, 

StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
                t.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
                Log.v("STERLITAMAK", errors.toString());

And get nothing.

Comment: Log.v("STERLITAMAK", t.toString());
Change Like This on `public void onFailure` method

    t.printstacktrace();
Then show logcat output

Comment: How can i find error log in logcat? @RajeshRajendiran

Comment: first change code like above comment then logcat show error on red color

Comment: @RajeshRajendiran [link](https://pastebin.com/d0cKrA2q)

Comment: I need Full Log for Your Application

Comment: @RajeshRajendiran https://pastebin.com/afZ4As5B sorry

Comment: Check response is coming from api

Comment: @RajeshRajendiran Api responses with my json array. If i use GETinstead of post, and choose **getJson** method in interface, i'll see my parameter. But problem only with POST.